# GetExitCodeProcess failing for process run in another session?

Tags: windows, api, session, process

I'm using the API function GetExitCodeProcess in the current logged on user session to monitor the exit code of a process. This process is run in another session (SYSTEM). 
The function returns immediately with an exit code of 0. 
I don't think this is correct.

Can anybody tell if this function will always fail / give wrong results if the process has been started in a different session?

My VB6 code is this, if anybody is interested:

```
Public Function GetProcExitCode(ByVal uProcID As Long) As Long

    Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103&
    Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400&

    Dim lProcHnd As Long
    lProcHnd = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, True, uProcID)

    Dim lTick As Long
    lTick = GetTickCount

    Dim lRet&
    lRet = 0

    'Wait for process end
    Do

        GetExitCodeProcess lProcHnd, lRet

    Loop While lRet = STILL_ACTIVE

    CloseHandle lProcHnd

    GetProcExitCode = lRet

    Dim lTicks&
    lTicks = GetTickCount() - lTick

    WriteLog "!!! GetExitCodeProcess needed " & lTicks & " ms."

End Function
```

Thank you.

Comment: You probably don't have the necessary permissions to open the process.

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx):

**Return value**

If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.

If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

---

Giving a return value of zero seems to be an error.

Comment: Your answer is great, I totally overlooked that. Perhaps somebody can give more insights, else I will accept your reply as the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think this needs more insight. The process exits with a return value of 0, and GetLastError returns 0, so this can't be right. If the process exited successfully, it wouldn't return with 0, and if it didn't, GetLastError would return non-zero. Right?

Comment: Perhaps I stand really stupid now, but I'm using GetExitCodeProcess so often, and to me, it is successful is the return value is 0. I have either found a big flaw in the MSDN, or I should wash my brain.

Comment: I would also like to add that GetExitCodeProcess returns before the process terminated, so this is totally wrong. I guess it has to do something with the fact that my "monitor" runs as the currently logged-in user, and the process runs under SYSTEM.

Comment: You're referring to the exit code of the function itself (which is a BOOL, so -1 or 0.) But I'm talking about the out parameter _Out_ LPDWORD lpExitCode.

Comment: @tmighty, a nitpicky and off-topic but important point: the return code is zero or nonzero.  Success isn't necessarily -1 in particular, it could be any nonzero number.